# R: "Error in matrix[i, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions"

Tags: arrays, r, function, matrix, dimensions

With DV and FF as vectors of length 47:

```
analyse <- function(DV,FF)
{
correct <- rep(0,47)
matrix <- array(rep(0,47*3), dim=c(47,3))

for(i in 1:47)
{
if(DV[i] > 50) {if(FF[i] > 50) {correct[i] <- i}
}
else
{
if(FF[i] < 0){correct[i] <- i}}
}

for(i in 1:47)
{
if((correct[i] == 0) == FALSE)
{
matrix[i,1] <- DV[i]
matrix[i,2] <- FF[i]
matrix[i,3] <- matrix[i,1] - matrix[i,2]
}
}

for(i in 47:1)
{
if(matrix[i,1]==0) {matrix<-matrix[-i]
}
}
return(matrix)
}
```

I do not understand why I am getting this error:

> *Error in matrix[i, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions*

Thanks in advance

[edit] sample data:

```
DV <- c(56.2, 59.2, 50.9, 46.9, 50.7, 47.3, 53.6, 57.8, 42.7, 45.0, 47.3, 44.1, 51.5, 50.0, 50.3, 50.4, 51.7, 47.8, 46.8, 40.0, 45.5, 57.4, 51.6, 36.1, 34.8, 41.2, 59.1, 62.5, 55.0, 53.8, 52.4, 44.5, 42.2, 50.1, 61.3, 49.6, 38.2, 51.1, 44.7, 40.8, 46.1, 53.5, 54.7, 50.3, 48.8, 53.7, 52.0)

DF <- c(49.95662, 51.93295, 53.02263, 50.00784, 48.55493, 49.93520, 48.70022, 50.98856, 52.51411, 47.02938, 47.86480, 48.70022, 47.53790, 50.22578, 49.68094, 49.78991, 49.82623, 50.29842, 48.88184, 48.51861, 46.04866, 48.04641, 52.36882, 50.26210, 44.63208, 44.15988, 46.48454, 52.98631, 54.22128, 51.49707, 51.06120, 50.55268, 47.68319, 46.84776, 49.71726, 53.78541, 49.53565, 45.39485, 50.08049, 47.75583, 46.33925, 48.26435, 50.95223, 51.38811, 49.78991, 49.24506, 51.02488)


[edit] result:

Scope of the function it to obtain a matrix which contains:
- every couple of DV[i] and FF[i] which are not both higher (or lower) than 50.
- their difference as third column.


example:

DV[1] = 55
FF[1] = 45

DV > 50 and FF < 50, so I report them in the matrix:

DV[1] -> matrix [1,1]
FF[1] -> matrix[1,2]
```

Third column being their difference:

```
matrix[1,3] <- matrix[1,1] - matrix[1,2].
```

With DV[2] = 55 and FF[2] = 55, analyse() does nothing because they're both higher than 50.

Comment: If you do things like `matrix <- matrix[-i]`, what do you expect?

Comment: Isn't it working, anyway? Could you correct me?

Comment: Your example isn't complete. You have not defined what `DV` or `FF` are as inputs. The loops are almost certainly not necessary. And spaces help to make your code more readable.

Comment: they're both two vectors of length 47. I don't need to make it essential, just a working code.

Comment: Code is not indented properly. It is unreadable. No spaces around operators especially `<-`. Please edit.

Comment: Please provide sample of your data (DV, FF). The function `dput()` from R makes it really simple

Comment: @Bhas edited. I'm sorry I'm a beginner: is it any better?

Comment: @ira what difference does the data make? they're both two vectors of length 47.

Comment: By providing an actual full example. If someone wants to help, they can compare your answer to theirs.

Comment: @PierreLafortune I added the actual values for DV and FF.

Comment: What exactly is this part supposed to do?: `if(matrix[i,1]==0) {matrix<-matrix[-i]
        }`

Comment: You are almost there. Please add the **result** that a proper `analyze` function would give for that example. Thank you for working on improving your question. I'm confident you'll get the help you need.

Comment: @ira it removes every row that contains zero values. I know it is an inefficient way, but for the moment it works. I am a beginner.

Comment: It may also be better to create an example with 10 values. That way you can focus on getting the structure correct. Afterwards, you can extend the logic to 47.

Comment: I am afraid `matrix[-i]` does something different than you think? Have you tried something like `matrix[-i, ]`

Comment: @ira yes, I meant [-i, ]. Is that the cause of the error? Now I try by correcting this. Thank you.

Comment: Your description is the opposite of what your function is doing. The values greater than 50 are being manipulated by the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the final for loop with a vectorized solution:

```
analyse <- function(DV,FF)
{
  correct <- rep(0,47)
  matrix <- array(rep(0,47*3),dim=c(47,3))

  for(i in 1:47)
  {
    if( DV[i] > 50 ) { 
      if( FF[i] > 50) {
        correct[i] <- i 
      } 
    }

    else {
      if( FF[i] < 0) {
        correct[i] <- i}
    }
  }

  for(i in 1:47)
  {
    if( (correct[i] == 0) == FALSE)
    {
      matrix[i,1] <- DV[i]
      matrix[i,2] <- FF[i]
      matrix[i,3] <- matrix[i,1] - matrix[i,2]
    }
  }

  matrix <- matrix[ matrix[,1] != 0, ]

  return(matrix)
}

analyse(DV, FF)
#      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
# [1,] 59.2 51.93295  7.26705
# [2,] 50.9 53.02263 -2.12263
# [3,] 57.8 50.98856  6.81144
# [4,] 51.6 52.36882 -0.76882
# [5,] 62.5 52.98631  9.51369
# [6,] 55.0 54.22128  0.77872
# [7,] 53.8 51.49707  2.30293
# [8,] 52.4 51.06120  1.33880
# [9,] 54.7 50.95223  3.74777
# [10,] 50.3 51.38811 -1.08811
# [11,] 52.0 51.02488  0.97512
```

But as you mentioned, this is inefficient. There is no need for loops. The below function provides identical output.

```
analyse2 <- function(DV, FF) {
  indx <- (DV > 50 & FF > 50) | FF < 0
  dif <- DV[indx] - FF[indx]
  matrix(c(DV[indx], FF[indx], dif), ncol=3)
}
analyse2(DV, FF)
#      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
# [1,] 59.2 51.93295  7.26705
# [2,] 50.9 53.02263 -2.12263
# [3,] 57.8 50.98856  6.81144
# [4,] 51.6 52.36882 -0.76882
# [5,] 62.5 52.98631  9.51369
# [6,] 55.0 54.22128  0.77872
# [7,] 53.8 51.49707  2.30293
# [8,] 52.4 51.06120  1.33880
# [9,] 54.7 50.95223  3.74777
# [10,] 50.3 51.38811 -1.08811
# [11,] 52.0 51.02488  0.97512

all.equal(analyse(DV, FF), analyse2(DV, FF))
[1] TRUE
```

**edit**

Based on your description, you want the values less than 50 to be reported to the matrix, not the values greater than 50 as you made in your original function. This is an edited function with an exclamation point added to the second line.

```
analyse2 <- function(DV, FF) {
  indx <- (!DV > 50 & FF > 50) | FF < 0
  dif <- DV[indx] - FF[indx]
  matrix(c(DV[indx], FF[indx], dif), ncol=3)
}

analyse2(DV, FF)
#      [,1]     [,2]      [,3]
# [1,] 46.9 50.00784  -3.10784
# [2,] 42.7 52.51411  -9.81411
# [3,] 50.0 50.22578  -0.22578
# [4,] 47.8 50.29842  -2.49842
# [5,] 36.1 50.26210 -14.16210
# [6,] 44.5 50.55268  -6.05268
# [7,] 49.6 53.78541  -4.18541
# [8,] 44.7 50.08049  -5.38049
```

**edit 2**

With either both greater or lesser than 50.

```
analyse3 <- function(DV, FF) {
  indx <- !( (DV > 50 & FF > 50) | (DV < 50 & FF < 50) )
  dif <- DV[indx] - FF[indx]
  matrix(c(DV[indx], FF[indx], dif), ncol=3)
}
```

Comment: The original function has DV > 50 and FF > 50. The description says values that are 'not both higher (or lower) than 50'. Which leads me now to believe that it is the negation of `(DV > 50 & FF > 50) | (DV < 50 & FF < 50)`

Comment: Yes, my description was correct and my code not. Thank you very much, also for the optimized function analyse2()!

Comment: Oh, my bad, I have read just the equation in the example. Sorry.

Comment: I added a third option with both lesser or both greater.